# Access to a website only when I grant them access

Tags: php, forms, authentication, e-commerce, registration

I have made a registration form and a login form using PHP.The registration form saves user's information to a database.

But as I am pretty new to PHP I want to achieve this think. I have also made a whole template/theme of an e-commerce website but I want as an entrance page to be this registration form and when I grant them access to be able to see the whole content of my e-commerce website.While i say grant them access when they give me the fields of the registration form,they wont be able to enter the website until I send them a password.So my question is how can i achieve not be able to see the entire website?What I need to do to protect it? i mean I need to add code on the registration form? on the login form or the template/theme?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

try using a $_SESSION variable. For example, create a $_SESSION['loggedIN'] variable that is initally false. The page would always verify that variable to allow or deny access to the content.

I'm guessing there is also a log-in form, right?

So, you would only allow acces ($_SESSION['loggedIN']=TRUE) once the log-in form action allows it. Of course there is all the verification and database access process, but that is a simple idea to solve your problem.

Comment: Ye there is a login form.Just the form is useless until I send them the password.Somehow I need to put all the website behind the front page and protect it!I will try it!

Comment: Agreed, I would just include a page/function at the top of every page that you want protected with the basic validation `if($_SESSION['loggedIN'] === false){ header('location:login_page.php')} `

Answer (score 2):

You would need to add code at the login page.
The code should handle the follwing:

1. Create $_SESSION[]
2. Create $_COOKIE[]
3. Create some secret way (databse) to know sessions and cookies are not forged.

At the time or page access is restricted to those who are logged in,

Check $_SESSION, $_COOKIE against the secret way (database)

Answer (score 2):

you need to track the registration process, for example track

- has been the email sended to user?
- when was the email sended to user?
- has user confirmed registration?

then set a column value `verified=(boolean)` to the main users table to check with a query if user is verified
then use sessions to store data after successful login, you need to make simple IFs after `session_start()` to restrict access or disable view of content.

```
    if(USER_HAS_ROLE){
     // display_content 
    }else{
     // don't display content
    }
    //----------------
    if(USER_IS_LOGGED_IN){
     // access website
    }else{
     // redirect to login page
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that doesn't seem to have been mentioned is that if the session loggedIn variable is false, after the header() redirect, the script should die() in case the user's browser ignores the Location: header.